# javascript function input validation

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write a javascript function which is called input() (performing input validation) and it will contain 3 arguments - the arguments are message, min and max.

I am having trouble bringing/writing the the function as a whole, have managed to work out bits of the function though - any help appreciated!

Code so far:

```
    // declare variables

var min = 5
var max = 20
var message = 'input must be between 5 and 20';

// get user input
input = parseInt(prompt(message));

// check range
while(isNaN(input) || input<min || input>max) {
    alert('input was invalid');
    input = parseInt(prompt(message));
}

// output validation
alert('input was accepted');
```

(from http://jsfiddle.net/AnJym/2/)

Comment: @sushilbharwani http://jsfiddle.net/AnJym/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

looks pretty good - the last thing to do is to declare a function and put your code in the "function body"

```
var input = function(min, max, message) {
    // your code
    return input;
}
```

you could also write `function input(min, max, message) { ... }`, but it's a matter of taste.

Now you can do `var i = input(5, 25, "input must been 5 and 25")` and `i` will contain the validated variable.

Answer (score 0):

Write above three lines in a funnction

```
function inputvalidation(){
var min = 5;
var max = 20;
var textvalue = document.getElementById('txtinput').value;
if(textvalue < 5 || textvalue > 20) {
  var message = 'input must be between 5 and 20';    
  }
}
```

call the function on click of a button.

Comment: The goal is to write a function that take three arguments

Comment: @OttoAllmendinger , Uncle Bob would tell you that it is a pretty bad way to do it: http://vimeo.com/13439458 =P

Comment: hmm...my bad...upvote to ur ans since the author of question got the ans from ur post.

Answer (score -1):

```
function input(min, max, message){
   var val = document.getElementById('InputControlToBeValidated').value;
   if(val>=min && val<=max){
      return true;
   }
   else{
      alert('input must be between '+ min +' and '+ max);
      return false;
   }
}
```

I hope this will help you